# Rails 4: How to replace primary key column using rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-migrations

I have an e-commerce application running in production, it was a Startup so when I created it I was a nobai, it has a big structural issue. My products table does not have an SKU column, Im working with default rails id's, I need to add a new column SKU and set it as primary key of `Product`, I found [this](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/) article that explains how to replace the default id with an SKU column, but it works when you are creating the table, but my app has thousands of products and thousands of users.

So what is the best practice for a production app to replace the current primary key `id` of the products table with a string SKU column? How to fix this structural issue?

Comment: Is the table `products` a `master` table for another tables? Are you going to change all related tables to change the foreign key? What it you just add a unique index to sku and set a not null constraint?

Comment: Do you think just adding an SKU column and set it to not null will make the trick for fix this structural issue? Yes I was thinking in replace all the foreign keys, replace `id` by `SKU`

Comment: Well, just my personal point of view: business domain should never be used for primary keys and foreign keys, business rules can change but change to relations in production can have a really big cost. Also DB JOINS using strings (I guess SKU is an string) are really heavy for databases. So yes, I think a NOT NULL and a UNIQUE should help you a lot. But once again, is just what a think.

Comment: I agree with @Aguardientico. I think you're much better off sticking with the existing PK of the products table, and simply add the SKU as a non-null column.  In an ecommerce app, the products table is going to be related to a lot of other tables. Changing the PK is likely going to cause you to have to make a lot of other changes.

Comment: Ok, do you think validating uniqueness from the model would be enough? or should I add that rule in the db migration?